# 19.04 "Settings" Application just stopped working

Tags: system-settings

Settings will not open. Icon is still present but when clicked it goes through the initial start but then does not open.

I have tried a purge and a desktop reinstall.

Comment: (gnome-control-center:12666): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 08:56:43.033: Settings schema 'com.system76.hidpi' is not installed
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
this is the error I get

Comment: Are you using Pop_OS?

Comment: no just added the pop theme, although i think i fixed it I ran   [sudo apt-get install hidpi-daemon] and it seems to fix the issue

Answer (score 12):

So I ran

```
sudo apt-get install hidpi-daemon
```

and it fixed the settings issue so weird but it popped into my head after this and I fixed it.

Comment: Facing the same issue and solved by your answer. Thanks a lot. Could you able to track why this happen and how this command solve this solution ?

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem, it's possible that the `gnome-control-center` package is not installed ( or it is, but not properly ).

I solved this issue by re-installing the package with this command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

Comment: I tried both of the commands and my settings windows just don't start, I suspect that could have something to do with my wacom drivers tablet, I'm running pop Os 19.04 any help please?!

Comment: So weird. I had the same problem in 22.04 and installing gnome-control-center resolved it for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by going to system monitor and killing `gnome-control-center` process.

After that opened settings and everything worked as it should!