# Gnome Settings not opening

Tags: nvidia, kernel, bootloader, system-settings

```
gnome-control-center
```

in terminal is giving

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And settings is not starting at all, just loading forever.

All this happened after I upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04

[image: screenshot]

Edit: After a restart, now the OS is not loading. Supposedly kernel is screwed.

```
[ OK ] Started GRUB failed boot detection.
[ 145.200501] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138360/19-04-settings-application-just-stopped-working]

Comment: `ldd $(which gnome-control-center)` please.

Comment: Can't tell, the problem escalated after a restart. Now it's not even booting up, kernal is having the issue i suppose.