# ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, gnome, bootloader

After upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04

```
[ OK ] Started GRUB failed
[ 145.200501] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
```

Tried recovery mode, what happened is in the pic attached. Supposedly due to some the graphic card (CUDA) issue.
(This happened after gnome settings were not opening, so I restarted)

[image]

Link of AskUbuntu thread:
[Gnome Settings not opening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186199/gnome-settings-not-opening)

Asked again on: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550422/ucsi-ccg-init-failed-110

Need help ;_;

Comment: A similar issue happened on my Dell computer. The issue lies in the hybrid graphics.
Go BIOS, and disable the hybrid graphics and reboot.
(In BIOS, it says that hybrid graphics is not supported by the Linux drivers)